# curl slist in threads

Tags: c, curl, pthreads

Have some trouble. I have one curl_slist object.

```
//global
struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: application/json");
...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  ... blabla checking 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsondata);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, oneheader);

  ... i have to share this curl handle with another thread, so i am making copy
  CURL* duphandle = curl_easy_duphandle(curl);
  ...push in thread duphandle and it will be performed sometime  
}
```

cgi handler

```
<?php
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
  echo $data
?>
```

So, the problem is that when i use header the result is

```
jsondata
empty
empty
empty
.....
```

Without header, if i send it in

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=" + jsondata);
```

it works fine

What the problem?

Comment: Are you *really* doing `"data=" + jsondata`? You can't append two strings with the `+` operator, that will just add an offset to the first pointer, most likely making the resulting pointer to be *way* off and leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: this is an abstract(pseudo code)

Comment: The questions are : Do I have to create a new slist? Why duphandle doesn't use header? I can't share it?

Comment: And you follow the note in the [`curl_easy_duphandle`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_duphandle.html): "**Note** that even in multi-threaded programs, this function must be called in a synchronous way, the input handle may not be in use when cloned."

Comment: this function is called in a synchronous way. I can't use duphandle in another thread?

Comment: As I read the reference, you *can* use it in another thread, you just have to do it in a synchronous way (i.e. using mutexes or the like), and not while the original handle is in use by e.g. [`curl_easy_perform`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68485/discussion-between-alldroll-and-joachim-pileborg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid. Have to use CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS because of threads. Sorry guys